# How to get week number from one month dates using R

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

Input:

| Dates |
| --- |
| 2012-02-01 |
| 2012-02-07 |
| 2012-02-15 |
| 2012-02-22 |
| 2012-02-28 |

Desired Output:

| Dates | Month_Of_Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-02-01 | 1 |
| 2012-02-07 | 2 |
| 2012-02-13 | 3 |
| 2012-02-15 | 3 |
| 2012-02-21 | 4 |
| 2012-02-22 | 4 |
| 2012-02-28 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$week_in_month <- 1 + 
  ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(df$Input_Dates), 
                              as.Date(paste0(substr(df$Input_Dates,1,8),'01')), units = "weeks")))
```

Output is:

```
  Input_Dates week_in_month
1  2012-02-01             1
2  2012-02-07             2
3  2012-02-15             3
4  2012-02-22             4
5  2012-02-28             5
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(Input_Dates = c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-07", "2012-02-15", 
"2012-02-22", "2012-02-28")), .Names = "Input_Dates", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: It worked partially. But if the have a Input data like 
Input_Dates = c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-07", "2012-02-14", "2012-02-15", 
                                     "2012-02-22", "2012-02-23", "2012-02-28")

Getting error : Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, week_in_month, value = c(1, 2, 3, 3,  : replacement has 6 rows, data has 5

Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case `Input_Dates` is a character vector then you can try `week_in_month <- 1 + ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(Input_Dates), as.Date(paste0(substr(Input_Dates,1,8),'01')), units = "weeks")))`